# Visual Basic: Freeform Pen?/Data Variance ignored when code "Handles" a state of that data?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, drawing, draw

```
Private Sub Form1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As     System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
    clicks += 1
    Select Case clicks Mod 2
        Case 1
            unclicked = 0
    End Select
    If Not already = 1 Then
        Do Until unclicked = 1
            already = 1
            If Not notgonnacrash = 1 Then
                area = Me.CreateGraphics
            End If
            Dim bun As Pen
            bun = New Pen(Drawing.Color.SandyBrown)
            notgonnacrash = 1
            Dim mouseposit = New Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
            If Not mouseposit = New Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y) Then
                area.DrawLine(bun, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, mouseposit.X, mouseposit.Y)
                mouseposit = New Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
            End If
            Select Case clicks Mod 2
                Case 1
                Case 0
                    unclicked = 1
                    already = 0
            End Select
            '   unclicked = 0

            btnstart.Text = "clickd"
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

or:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClickBun(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown

    If Not n = 1 Then

        area = Me.CreateGraphics
    End If
    Dim bun As Pen
    bun = New Pen(Drawing.Color.SandyBrown)
    n = 1
    Dim f As Integer = 0
    Do
        Dim mouseposit = New Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            If Not mouseposit = New Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y) Then
                area.DrawLine(bun, MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, mouseposit.X, mouseposit.Y)
                mouseposit = New Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y)
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

I have a school project due soon which I am ambitious enough to attempt this for. Herein lies the main problem...:

I've tried many variations of this program (including an adaptation with insteaed of Handles mybase.click I used Handles Me.Mousedown and me.mouseup and beginning drawing based off of whether or not you had the left mouse down), but in all of the programs it seems that it solidifies all received data at the beginning and doesn't adjust. A request of mine of the computer, for example: if the left button is no longer pressed down, you should stop executing this code. but apparently the left being pressed down never changes in that sub of Handles left down-- it keeps on drawing. its like the sub cannot fathom the case which initiated it no longer being valid. Why? Am I just a terrible programmer? Why won't this above one stop drawing either? I'm desperate, please!
(If it wasn't clear this is supposed to be a freeform pen that you can draw with on the form, turning it on or off whenever you want, whether simply by holding down on the left button or toggling it on or off with the left button, whichever I can get to work.)

Comment: I cant find a clear problem statement, but a) CreateGraphics is usually the wrong way to draw b) you are creating a new pen on every MouseDown and disposing of none of them  You should just need a simple bool flag that is set when the mouse is down, then cleared when the mouse is up.

Comment: Please fix your tags.  VBA and VB.NET aren't the same language.